# Access a layout template from a blueprint template folder

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a blueprint with its own template folder.  There is also a base layout template in the "top" templates folder.  I want to access this template from a blueprint template.  I tried the following but got a "Template Not Found" error.

```
{% extends "../../../../../templates/layout.j2" %}
```

The package looks like this:

```
__init__.py
├── modules
│   └── citrixlb
│       ├── citrixlb.py
│       └── templates
└── templates
    └── layout.j2
```

I set up the blueprint's `template_folder`:

```
citrix = Blueprint('citrix', __name__, template_folder='templates', url_prefix='/citrix')
```

What is the correct way to reference a template from another template directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flask's Jinja loader [flattens](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/7d506f2408520ecb21025f93d9ece00431004501/flask/app.py#L704) the global folder and all blueprint folders into a common tree, prioritizing the global folder.  So simply refer to the template as if it was at the top level location.

```
{% extends "layout.j2" %}
```

Note that by using the "j2" extension rather than ".html", you've probably inadvertently disabled [automatic escaping](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/7d506f2408520ecb21025f93d9ece00431004501/flask/app.py#L720).  It is recommended that you use the ".html" extension for html templates.